# $f=0$ almost everywhere

Tags: measure-theory

be $G\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ a open set. Be $f:G\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$* measured and for all  interval $[a,b] \subseteq G$ to have that $f$ is lebesgue integrable function in $[a,b]$ and $\int_{a}^b f dm=0$. Show that $f=0$ almost everywhere.

I know that if for all set measured $A\subseteq E$, if $\int_{A}f=0$ so $f=0$ almost everywhere, I try to use this for the problem but dont work.

thanks

Comment: Hint: Which structure has the collection of the Borel subsets $A$ of $\mathbb R$ such that the integral of $f$ on $A$ is zero?

Comment: I think the borel set $F_{\delta}$

Comment: is $\mathrm{d}m$ Lebesgue measure?

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\d}{\ \mathrm d}$
Another way to approach this is by using the [Lebesgue differentiation theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem) (LDT).

Since $G$ is open, given $x\in G$, there is a $\delta\gt 0$ such that $(x-\delta, x+\delta)\subseteq G$. This says that for any $\delta\gt 0$, small enough, we can consider $\int_{x-\delta}^{x+\delta} f(t)\d m(t)$. Therefore
$$\begin{align*}
f(x) &= \lim_{\delta\to 0} \frac1{2\delta}\int_{x-\delta}^{x+\delta} f(t)\d m(t)\quad\text{a.e.} &&\text{by LDT}\\
&= \lim_{\delta\to 0} \frac1{2\delta}\cdot 0\quad\text{a.e.} &&\text{by your hypothesis}\\
&= 0\quad\text{a.e.}
\end{align*}$$
as we wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $f(x) > \epsilon  >0$ on some $A \subseteq G$ such that $\mu (A) >0.$ Since $G$ is open, there exists open $U$ with $A \subseteq U \subseteq G.$ Note that $U$ can be written as the countable union of disjoint intervals $\displaystyle\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} I_n$ with each $I_n \subseteq G.$  Hence $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \displaystyle\int_{I_n} f d\mu = \displaystyle\int_U f d\mu  \ge \displaystyle\int_A f d\mu > \epsilon \cdot \mu (A) >0,$ a contradiction.

Comment: you sure the the existence of that interval?

Comment: No, in fact I was wrong. Check the edit.

Comment: with your argument I just write G like union disjoint intervals,and what type of intervals you take?

Comment: Well, my argument writes $U$ as countable union of disjoint intervals. The sum on the left has to be zero by your assumption.

Comment: I noticed you haven't accepted any answers to the questions you've posted. Without intimating that you ought to accept mine (it is less elegant than the others), it is MSE custom to accept an answer that you feel has sufficiently answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

The Lebesgue measure is based on the borelian $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$. That means that measurable sets come as a limit of open and closed sets in terms of unions and intersections. That implies that for every measurable set $A$, there is a sequence of unions of intervals $I_n$ such that $\chi_{I_n}\to \chi_A$ pointwise. Because:
$$
\int_{I_n}fd\mu=\int \chi_{I_n}fd\mu
$$
then in each $A$ where the integral makes sense, there will be a 0 limit. And then you can use your argument. That works also for functions that are not necessarily positive.

Answer (score 0):

Although this  is a very old problem in MSE, I would like to present yet another solution. It is enough to assume that $f$ is Borel-measurable.

Starting with any interval of the form $I_n:=[-n,n]$, consider the class $\mathcal{D}_n$ of (Borel) measurable sets $A\subset[-n,n]$ such that $\int_Af\,dm=0$.

1. $\mathcal{D}_n$ contains $I_n$, and all intervals $[a,b]\subset[-n,n]$.
2. $\mathcal{D}_n$ is a $d$-system, that is, if $A,\,B\in\mathcal{D}_n$ and $B\subset A$, then $A\setminus B\in\mathcal{D}_n$; if $\{A_m:m\in\mathbb{N}\}\subset\mathcal{D}_n$ and $A_n\nearrow A$, then $A=\bigcup_mA_m\in\mathcal{D}_n$.
3. The collections of intervals $[a,b]\subset[-n,n]$ is closed under intersection (a $\pi$--system) and generate the collection $\mathscr{B}_n$ of all Borel measurable sets in $[-n,n]$.

It follows from [Dynkin's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynkin_system) that $\mathcal{D}_n=\mathscr{B}_n$. In particular, $\{x\in[-n,n]:f>0\},\{x\in [-n,n]: f<0\}\in\mathcal{D}_n$ whence we conclude  that $f=0$ $m$-a.s. in $[-n,n]$.

This method has the advantage that it can be generalized to any ($\sigma$--finite) measure $m$ on $(\mathbb{R},\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}))$.