# Is the condition $ \intop_{a}^{b}f\left(s\right)ds=0 $ for any $ a,b \in \mathbb{R} $ enough to conclude that $f=0$ almost everywhere?

Tags: real-analysis

Assume we have $ f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R} $,Riemann integrable in any closed interval, such that for any $ a,b \in \mathbb{R} $ the following condition holds $$ \intop_{a}^{b}f\left(s\right)ds=0 $$

Is it enough to conclude that $ f =0 $ almost evereywhere?
If so, how can we prove it? Is it trivial?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? Any idea how to start?

Comment: Assuming of course that $f$ is measurable. You can use monotone class arguments for example: Consider the measurable sets $A$ where $\int_A f=0$, notice that they have some type of interesting structure, and then see how that is related to intervals.

Comment: See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/157997/42969

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$f=0$ almost everywhere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157997/f-0-almost-everywhere)

Comment: @Oliver Diaz The comments in the other post refer to Lebesgue integration which Im not familier with, my question is about Riemman integrable and I prefer answers which using Riemman integration theorems rather then Lebesgue

Comment: @FreeZe: I would suggest that you make an edit to your OP and add that assumption that $f$ is Riemann integrable in any interval. The "almost everywhere" adjective makes many people (like me) think immediately about Lebesgue integration, which is the type of integral one matures into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we define the integral using the Riemann integral, then there is a nice elementary approach:

First restrict our attention to an interval $[L_1, L_2]$, and we have that for any $[a,b]$ contained in $[L_1, L_2]$, the integral of f is $0$

(1) Define $osc (a,  \delta) = \sup |f(x)-f(y)|$ such that $x,y$ are in $D_\delta(a)$ and define $osc(a)$ = $\lim _{\delta \rightarrow 0} osc (a,  \delta)$

(2) Prove that for any Riemann integrable function, $\{x: osc(x)>0\}$ is of measure $0$. Note that no advanced measure theory is needed for this statement. We will simply need that we can find open intervals of arbitrarily small total length which cover the set.

Hint: we simply need to show that for any given rational $q$, $\{x: osc(x)>q\}$ is of measure zero. As the rationals are denumerable, the result would then follow.

(3) Observe that $osc(x)=0$ implies that $f$ is continuous at $x$

(4) At the points where $f$ is continuous, clearly it must be zero, or we could construct an interval on which its integral was non zero.

(5) As the points of discontinuity were measure $0$, we are done.

Unfortunately, I only cover lebesgue integration next year in my course, so apologies if that isn't what you are looking for, but hopefully it is interesting :)

Comment: yes this proof is only for riemann integrable functions (i left a comment at the end of the proof)

Comment: Indeed my question is about Riemman integral. Thanks, that is very helpful

Comment: As a reference, this is a very similar technique as used in Stein and Shakarchi, 'Fourier Analysis', in the appendix on riemann integration, which I just adapted a bit:)